# How to change values into functions using Buttons in Python 3.4

Tags: python, variables, button, tkinter

I'm trying to change 'number' in a function called from a Tkinter Button as in `function2` below.  `function1` recognizes 'number' and works fine, `function2` gives an `UnboundLocalError`.  If I try to pass the value in the Button(like: `command=function2(number)`) the function is executed immediately without pressing the button.  Can someone help?

```
from tkinter import *

def function1():
    print('In pcomm.')
    print('number=', str(number))

def function2():
    print('In acomm.')
    print('number=', str(number))
    number += 1  #UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment
    print('number=', str(number))

#create the window
root = Tk()

number = 2
print('Just assigned: number=', str(number))

printButton = Button(root, text = "Press to print.", command = function1).grid()
addButton = Button(root, text = "Press for number+=1.", command = function2).grid()


#kick off the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: number needs to be global for this to work.  i.e. add `global number` at the top of `function2()`.  For what it's worth, that is a band-aid solution -- Generally working with global data isn't the _best_ approach.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I'm still looking for a way change variables using a Button without going global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the global, you'd want to use a class.

```
class AppData(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 2

    def function1(self):
        print('In pcomm.')
        print('number=', str(self.number))

    def function2(self):
        print('In acomm.')
        print('number=', str(self.number))
        self.number += 1
        print('number=', str(self.number))
```

You would then create an instance of the class, and pass it's bound methods to the buttons...

```
app = AppData()
addButton = Button(root, text = "Press for number+=1.", command = app.function2)
addButton.grid()
```

Note that you'll frequently see the button as part of another (or the same) class.

Comment: Put "self" in the functions and it worked fine, otherwise got a TypeError.  Thanks!

Comment: @Matt -- Whoops.  Sorry about that :-).